# Почему в переменную не попадает значение?

Tags: python, tkinter, переменные

Почему в `welcome_txt` попадает `user_name = None`,
как это можно исправить?

```py
from tkinter import *


def user_name_check(user_name):
    if user_name == "":
        return 2

    symbols = '! " # $ % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ .'
    for s in user_name:
        if s in symbols:
            return 1
    else:
        return 0


def game():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Привет, я игра 'Угадай персонажа'.")
    # window.geometry('1280x720')

    f1 = Frame(window)
    f2 = Frame(window)
    f3 = Frame(window)
    f4 = Frame(window)

    for frame in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

    uncorrect = Label(f1)
    uncorrect.pack(side='bottom')

    def raise_frame(frame):
        frame.tkraise()

    def user_inpt(event):
        user_name = name_input.get()
        result = user_name_check(user_name)
        if result == 2:
            uncorrect.config(text="Вы не ввели имя.")

        if result == 1:
            uncorrect.config(
                text="В имени найдены запрещенные символы или пробел.\nИмя должно содержать только буквы английского,"
                     "\nрусского алфавитов и цифры, введите имя еще раз.")

        if result == 0:
            uncorrect.config(text="")
            raise_frame(f2)

    name = Label(f1, text="Введите имя:  ")
    name.pack()

    user_name = None

    name_input = Entry(f1)
    name_input.pack()

    but = Button(f1, text="Играть")
    but.bind('<Button-1>', user_inpt)
    but.pack()

    welcome_txt = Label(
        f2,
        text=f"{user_name}, чтобы начать игру, напиши - что-нибудь, чтобы завершить игру напиши - 'Стоп'."
    ) 'Почему то сюда попадает user_name с заданным значением None((('
    welcome_txt.pack()

    raise_frame(f1)

    window.mainloop()


game()
```

Comment: А как можно изменить значение user_name в функции user_inpt?

Comment: Напишите `global user_name` в самом начале функции `user_inpt`

Comment: @Master'sTime можете пожалуйста написать где, я сейчас попробовал, все равно выводит None.

Comment: Да, именно там.

Comment: Только не `global` а `nonlocal`.

Comment: Тоже None( @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Но это не поможет. `Label` вызывается до ввода имени.

Comment: Научитесь менять Label на лету.

Comment: Я понял как исправить, добавил welcome_txt прямо в функцию user_inpt,  большое спасибо за наводку! @StanislavVolodarskiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял что welcome_txt добавлял раньше чем user_name изменялся, вот как исправил.

```
def user_inpt(event):
    nonlocal user_name
    user_name = name_input.get()
    result = user_name_check(user_name)
    if result == 2:
        uncorrect.config(text="Вы не ввели имя.")

    if result == 1:
        uncorrect.config(
            text="В имени найдены запрещенные символы или пробел.\nИмя должно содержать только буквы английского,"
                 "\nрусского алфавитов и цифры, введите имя еще раз.")

    if result == 0:
        uncorrect.config(text="")

        welcome_txt = Label(
            f2,
            text=f"{user_name}, чтобы начать игру, напиши - что-нибудь, чтобы завершить игру напиши - 'Стоп'."
        )
        welcome_txt.pack()

        raise_frame(f2)
```